# Bind a char[] in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, char

I have a char[] propertie.
I would like to bind it, but i display "system.char[]" instead of the char[]value.

**Here is my XAML :**

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{ Binding Path= strEvtNumero}" Header="  N° évènement   " Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"  />
```

**Here is my propertie :**

```
public char[] strEvtNumero
    {
        get { return m_strEvtNumero; }
        set
        {
            m_strEvtNumero = value;
            FirePropertyChangedEvent("strEvtNumero");
        }
    }
```

Have you an idea please ?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wrap it into another property

```
    string strEvtNumeroString
    {
        get
        {
            return strEvtNumero.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            strEvtNumero = value.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

or use value converter

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [value converter](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) to show the right value.